# OpenGL program lags every now and then

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using C++ with SDL 2, OpenGL 3.3, Windows 8.  Whenever I run my program, the time it takes to draw each frame is usually`< 1 ms`, as I am only drawing a few hundred quads.  It is batched drawing, and they all have the same texture.  I am not querying the GPU.  I have tried calling `glFlush()` at the end of every frame.  But every once in a while, the time it takes to draw suddenly jumps up to `3-5 ms`.  Sometimes it jumps to even 30 ms.  What can I do to fix this?

```
void XL::SpriteBatch::render()
{
    generateElements();

    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexCount * 8 * sizeof(vertexBuffer[0]), vertexBuffer.data());
    glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, ebOffset * sizeof(elementBuffer[0]), elementBuffer.data());

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount / 4 * 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    vertexBuffer.clear();
    elementBuffer.clear();
    vertexCount = 0;
    ebOffset = 0;
}
```

Comment: Impossible to say without actually seeing any code, or performance analysis!

Comment: Hi.  I have edited the code in.  It's very simple, and I am certain the bug does not lie elsewhere, as I have tested very extensively.  It is the glBufferSubData and the glDrawElements calls that sometimes take more time than usual.

Comment: BufferSubData triggers syncronisation point, because pipeline may be drawing data from buffer you're currently replacing. Consider using two buffers and switching them between frames, much like display doublebuffering does.

Comment: Ah, so I would have to create two vertex buffers and two element buffers, correct?

Comment: At least two pairs of buffers, yes. And watch buffer size, of course, you can't overflow it. Ideally buffer data should be static, but I suppose it isn't much an option in case of sprites.

Comment: Double buffering is one way of doing it. Another is buffer orphaning. See this page for some techniques: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming